# Identity Server 4 cookie setup not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

I have been tasked with adding an mvc website to an existing web api project that uses Identity Server 4. Currently the web api authenticates Android clients using bearer tokens.

I would like the mvc site to use cookies which contain the bearer token.

I have been struggling with this for a few days now and I can make either the web client work, or the android client work, but not both. If I remove the default scheme, from the AddAuthentication(), the website will work as intended. This however causes the android client to not authorize users (HttpClient.User.Claims is null). If I do add the default scheme, the android client will work, but the website will not pick up the claims.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

[Image showing no claims being picked up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCze2.png)

Here is my current setup:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) //TODO If I remove this default then the android client stops working (the web client will only work with this removed)
           .AddCookie(options =>
           {
               options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Development/Account/Login");
               options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Development/Account/Login");
               options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Development/Account/Logout");
               options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
           })
           .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options => 
           {
               var configAuthority = container.GetInstance<IOptions<CoPilotConfig>>().Value?.IdentityAuthority;
               options.Authority = configAuthority ?? $"http://localhost:{Constants.LOOPBACK_PORT}";
               options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
               options.ApiName = "CoPilotApi";
           });
```

Here is the method used to login on the website portion:

```
 [HttpPost("Login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        string deviceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        string userString = deviceId + @"\" + _ctx.Company + @"\" + model.Username;
        var accessToken = await GenerateTokenAsync(userString, model.Password);

        if (accessToken != "invalid_grant")
        {
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            JwtSecurityToken jwtToken = handler.ReadToken(accessToken) as JwtSecurityToken;
            jwtToken.Claims.ToList();
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(jwtToken.Claims.ToList(), IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme);
            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                AllowRefresh = true,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
            };

            try
            {
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);
            }
            catch (Exception e){}

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Map");
        }
        else
        {
            model = new LoginModel();
            model.Exception = "Invalid username or password";
            return View("~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml", model);
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> GenerateTokenAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        var clientList = IdentityServerConfig.GetClients();
        Client client = clientList.FirstOrDefault();

        string tokenUrl = $"http://" + HttpContext.Request.Host.ToString() + "/connect/token";
        TokenClient tokenClient = new TokenClient(tokenUrl, client.ClientId, "secret");
        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(username, password, client.AllowedScopes.FirstOrDefault());
        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
            return "invalid_grant";

        return tokenResponse.AccessToken;
    }
```

Any ideas on how to fix this or another way of handling this issue without having to modify the Android client?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. To anyone trying this you add a middleware to determine which scheme to use for the incoming request:

```
 public class AuthSchemeMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, Func<Task> next)
    {
        var scheme = context.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("idsrv.session")
            ? "Cookies" : "Bearer";

        var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync(scheme);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            context.User = result.Principal;
        }
        await next();
    }
}
```

You will call the new middleware here:

```
 // use Authentication from IdentityServer4
 app.UseAuthentication();

 // Serve static files
 app.UseDefaultFiles();
 app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
 {
     ContentTypeProvider = ContentTypeProviderFactory.GetContentTypeProvider()
 });

 app.UseMiddlewareFrom<AuthSchemeMiddleware>(container);
 app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

Authentication should be added like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Cookies";
            })
           .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
           {
               options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Development/Account/Login");
               options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Development/Account/Login");
               options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Development/Account/Logout");
               options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
           });

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                var configAuthority = container.GetInstance<IOptions<CoPilotConfig>>().Value?.IdentityAuthority;
                options.Authority = configAuthority ?? $"http://localhost:{Constants.LOOPBACK_PORT}";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ApiName = "CoPilotApi";
            });
```